# How do I enter debug mode for my widget tests on Flutter in AndroidStudio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-test

When it comes to starting debug mode while deploying my app to my device in AndroidStudio the debug button is green and clickable:
[image]

If I however want to start debug mode for my tests it is greyed out:
[image]

Is there a way for me to enter debug mode to better understand why my tests fail?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Debug mode is available when Debugging individual files but not when Debugging folders/All tests.

This means it requires adding a new run configuration (via edit configuration):
[image]
Click new configuration:
[image]
Select Flutter Test and end up at:
[image]
You need the Test scope All in file and can select the testfile that you want to debug and use the debugger with it.